# Show that if $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous function if and only if the graph of $f$ is a closed subset of $X\times Y$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

> Given a function $f:X\to Y$, we define the graph of $f$ as the set
>   $$G(f)=\{(x,f(x)),x\in X\}$$ Show that if $X$ is compact then $f$ is a
>   continous function if and only if $G(f)$ is a closed subset of
>   $X\times Y$.

I know that a set $X$ is called compact when every open cover of $X$ have a finite subcover. Then I need to show that

- If $f$ is continous then $G(f)$ is a closed subset of $X\times Y$.
- If $G(f)$ is a closed subset of $X\times Y$ then $f$ is continous.

How I can show that?

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that says that $X\subset \mathbb R.$

Comment: Should there be?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I think not, at least it is not said in the question.

Comment: Show some effort you made, I think the first assertion is easy.

Comment: The second assertion requires some compactness/Hausdorff conditions iirc

Comment: $Y$ compact makes "graph closed implies continuous " true. Without it there's a counterexample.

Comment: @henno provides relevant insight on this material in his answer @ https://math.stackexchange.com/a/440772/432081 (compact graphs and continuity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your purported equivalence can fail in both directions, if we don't add extra assumptions on $Y$.

The implication $G(f)$ closed implies $f$ continuous can fail for compact $X$:

Let $X = [0,1]$ in the cofinite topology; this is a compact space. 
Let $Y = [0,1]$ in the discrete topology.

Define $f(x) =x$ from $X$ to $Y$, then $f$ is not continuous, as $f^{-1}[\{0\}] = \{0\}$ is not open in $X$, but $\{0\}$ *is* open in $Y$.

But $G(f)$ is closed in $X \times Y$: suppose $(p,q) \notin G(f)$, then $q \neq p$ and then the set $(X\setminus\{q\}) \times \{q\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $(p,q)$ that misses $G(f)$.

We can drop the compactness of $X$ and replace it by the compactness of $Y$; then the implication does hold:

Suppose then that $G(f)$ is closed. Kuratowski's theorem says that $\pi_X: X \times Y \to X$ is a closed map for compact $Y$.
Let $C \subseteq Y$ be closed and check that:

$$f^{-1}[C] = \pi_X[(X \times C)\cap G(f)]$$ which is the image of a closed set of $X \times Y$ under $\pi_X$, so $f^{-1}[C]$ is closed for all closed $C \subseteq Y$, meaning that $f$ is continuous.

The implication $f$ continuous implies $G(f)$ closed can also fail for compact $X$ (even for compact $Y$):

Let $X = \{0,1\}$ in the discrete topology, $Y$ the same set in the indiscrete (trivial) topology. Again $f$ is the identity. This $f$ is continuous, but a basic open neighbourhood $(0,1)$ contains $\{0\} \times \{0,1\}$ which intersects $G(f)$. So $(0,1) \in \overline{G(f)} \setminus G(f)$, so $G(f)$ is not closed.

If we add the condition that $Y$ is Hausdorff, we don't need compactness of $X$ at all to see that $f: X \to Y$ continuous implies $G(f)$ is closed. This then always holds.

Comment: @ henno  sir  im not  getting that how ( x\{q})   $\times$  {$ {q}$}  is  an open neighbhourhood of $(p,q)$ ?

Comment: Also   why (0,1)   look like {0}$ \times$ {0,1} ?

Comment: @lomber because of how the product topology is defined

Comment: @lomber I said that $(0,1)$ has that set as a minimal neighbourhood

Comment: i  mean {p} =(x\{q}) ???? is  it  right @henno sir

Comment: @lomber $X\setminus \{q\}$ is open in $X$ and $\{q\}$ is open in $Y$ so their product is an open set containing $(p,q)$ in $X\times Y$.

Comment: thanks  a   lots  @henno  sir,,,,,,can  u guide   me  how  can  i  learned topology  in  easy  way  as  im  reading  the  munkre topology,,now,,,as  some  problem  are  easy and some problem  are very  tough,,,,even  sometime   did n't  understands   solution  of the  question also ??  can u   sugggest  or guide  me???

Comment: @lomber keep doing exercises. Study examples. make up your own examples. That's the main thing: actively doing it. IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Proof of the first assertion under the condition  $Y$ is a Hausdorff space:
Let $(x_i,f(x_i))$ be a net in $G(f)$ such that $(x_i,f(x_i))\to (x,y)$, then $x_i\to x$ and $f(x_i)\to y$, hence $y=\lim f(x_i)=f(x).$

If $Y$ is not Hausdorff, then the first assertion may fail: Let $X=\{0,1\}$ with discret topology, $Y=\{0,1\}$ with trivial topology, and $f=\operatorname{id}$.
It's easy to find the contradition.

A counterexample for the second assertion:
Let $X=[0,1]$ with euclidean topology, $Y=[0,1] $ with discret topology, and $f=\operatorname{id}_{[0,1]}$. Then $f$ is not continuous obviously, but the graph is closed.

Indeed, suppose $(x_i,x_i)$ is a net in $G(f)$ such taht $(x_i,x_i)\to  (x,y)$, then $x_i\to x$ and $x_i\to y$, thus there exists some $i_0 $ such that $x_i=y\forall i\geq i_0$ since $\{y\}$ is a neiborhood of $y$, hence $x=y,$ i.e. $(x,y)\in G(f).$

However, the following is true:

> Suppose $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $Y$ is a topological space, then $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff the graph of $f$ is compact.
>   See [Graph of continuous function from compact space is compact.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440676/graph-of-continuous-function-from-compact-space-is-compact?rq=1) for the proof.

Thank William for correcting mistakes.

Comment: As X is assumed to be compact, X = R cannot be used as a counter example.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Oh,just replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $[0,1]$

Comment: But the ordinary topology of Y = {0,1} is discrete, the same as X, both Hausdorff.

Comment: @WilliamElliot no, the topology on $Y$ is $\{\emptyset ,Y\}$.

Comment: In the second line, x -> x_i is another mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement, as been shown, has some problems.
Instead, I suggest it be replaced by proving the following.

If Y is Hausdorff and f:X -> Y is continuous, then G(f) is closed.
If Y is compact and G(f) is closed, then f:X -> Y is continuous.

For the second one, show the inverse image of a closed set is closed.
Useful for that is pi_1:XxY -> X is closed.

Theorem
compact Y implies pi_1:XxY -> X closed.
Proof.
Let K be a closed subset of XxY.
lemma:  U \cap pi_1(K) empty iff UxY \cap K empty

Assume x not in pi_1(K).  Hence
{x} \cap pi_1(K) and {x}xY \cap K are empty  .

By the tube lemma there's
some open U,V with {x}xY subset UxV subset (XxY)\K.

Whereupon UxY \cap K and U \cap pi_1(K) are empty since V = y  .
As x in U, x not in cl pi_1(K).

Thusly cl pi_1(K) subset pi_1(K) which shows pi_1(K) is closed.

There is a converse.
Y compact iff for all X, pi_1:XxY -> X closed.

Comment: why $p_1$ is closed without assuming that $X$ is compact？

Comment: Because it's a map from the (compact) graph to the Hausdorff domain @C.Ding .

Comment: @HennoBrandsma There is no assumption that the domain is Huasdorff.

Comment: @C.Ding.  I have added the proof to my answer.

Comment: @C.Ding I also don't see an assumption that $Y$ is compact either.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma William is right: $Y$ is compact iff for  all $X$, $\pi_1:X\times Y\to X$ is closed. see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679262/show-that-x-times-y-rightarrow-y-is-a-closed-map-give-an-example-where-proj for proof.       And he does assume $Y$ compact in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer starts out as providing hints/techniques that will be fleshed out to a full answer as I get the time. It is hoped that the details will be more than sufficient for the interested reader to follow.

---

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces. For any $y_0 \in Y$, we have the constant mapping

$f_{y_0}: x\mapsto y_0$

Note that the $\text{Graph of } f_{y_0} = X \times \{y_0\}$, and we regard it as a subspace of the topological product $X \times Y$.

The reader is advised to review the [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set#General_definition) of open cylinder and cylinder set in the product topology.

Proposition 1: $Y$ is Hausdorff $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow$ the graphs of any two different constant mappings can be separated by open sets in $X \times Y$.

Proof: The '$\Rightarrow$'direction is very easy by using open cylinders and remembering how to [intersect Cartesian products](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Intersections).

For the '$\Leftarrow$'direction, let $U_{y_o}$ (resp. $U_{y_1}$) be an open set containing  the $\text{Graph of } f_{y_0} = X \times \{y_0\}$ (resp. $\text{Graph of } f_{y_1} = X \times \{y_1\}$) such that

$U_{y_o} \cap U_{y_1} = \emptyset$

Select any point $x$ in $X$. Corresponding to this point are the two points $(x,y_o) \in U_{y_o}$ and $(x,y_1) \in U_{y_1}$. We know both of these two points are contained in cylinder sets contained in the corresponding open $U \text{ Set}$. As subsets of disjoint sets, these cylinder sets must also be disjoint. We know that $x$ appears as a first coordinate in both of these (open cartesian) cyclinder sets. According to the [Cartesian Product of Intersections](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Intersections) rule, the 2nd coordinate opens sets containing $y_0$ and $y_1$ for each cylinder set must be disjoint, so $Y$ is Hausdorff.

---

Proposition 2: Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces. Then

$f: X \to Y$ is continuous iff the mapping $x \mapsto (x,f(x))$ from $X$ into the product space $X \times Y$ is continuous.

Comment: This argument basically shows that if $Y$ is such that the left to right implication of the OP's always holds, then $Y$ must be Hausdorff.