# $Y$ is Hausdorff, then: $f:X\to Y$ is countinous $\Leftrightarrow$ graph of $F$ is closed in $X\times Y$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

The following statement is given:

$X$ is a topological space and $Y$ is a Hausdorff space, then $f:X\to Y$ is countinous iff $\mathcal{G}(f)$ is closed in $X\times Y$, when $\mathcal{G}(f) := \{(x,y)\in X\times Y: f(x) = y\}$

**Note:** The statement was given as *true*, to be proven, as part of an assignment. Also, no additional condition was given for $X$, $Y$.

One direction of statement (the graph of a a continuous function to Hausdorff space is closed in the product), is certainly true. However, the opposite direction seems false (although it does hold, if $Y$ is compact). The following is an attempt to provide a counterexample.

Assume $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, and define: $$f:X\to Y \\ f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x},&x\neq 0\\0,&x=0\end{cases} $$
Every point $x\in (X\times Y)\setminus \mathcal{G}(f)$ has some nbhd that is a subset of $(X\times Y)\setminus \mathcal{G}(f)$, so $(X\times Y)\setminus \mathcal{G}(f)$ is union of such nbhds and thus is an open set, implying $\mathcal{G}(f)$ is closed.

The interval $(-1,1)$ is an open subset of $Y=\mathbb{R}$, but: $$f^{-1}((-1,1)) = (-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)\cup \{0\}$$ is not an open subset of $X=\mathbb{R}$, so $f$ is not continuous.

Is this a proper disproof, or is there some mistake?

Comment: The converse is indeed false. Closed graph does not imply continuity and your counterexample seems to work.

Comment: I believe you need the further assumption that $Y$ is compact for the converse to hold. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem

Comment: See this related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324482/show-that-if-fx-to-y-is-a-continuous-function-if-and-only-if-the-graph-of-f?rq=1)