# $f$ is a > continous function if and only if $G(f)$ is a closed subset of > $X\times Y$.

Tags: general-topology

> Given a function $f:X\to Y$, we define the graph of $f$ as the set
>   $$G(f)=\{(x,f(x)),x\in X\}$$ Show that if $X$ is compact then $f$ is a
>   continous function if and only if $G(f)$ is a closed subset of
>   $X\times Y$.

As  i found the  answer  here...[Show that if $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous function if and only if the graph of $f$ is a closed subset of $X\times Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324482/show-that-if-fx-to-y-is-a-continuous-function-if-and-only-if-the-graph-of-f)
but  im not getting  in my head as  im not able to understand this paragraph......

If $Y$ is not Hausdorff, then the first assertion may fail: Let $X=\{0,1\}$ with discret topology, $Y=\{0,1\}$ with trivial topology, and $f=\operatorname{id}$.
It's easy to find the contradition...

PLiz  elaborate this  this   answer   with  proper proof,,,,,

Answer (score 3):

If $Y=\{0,1\}$ with trivial topology, then any map to $Y$ is continuous. So in particular, this is the case if we take $X=\{0,1\}$ with discrete topology (a compact space) and $f\colon x\mapsto x$. So the claim tells us that $G(f)$ should be a closed subset of $X\times Y$, or equivalently, its complement open. However, any open subset of $X\times Y$ that contains $(1,0)$ must also contain $(0,0)$. We conclude that $G(f)$ is not closed.