# $f:X\rightarrow Y$, with $Y$ compact, is continuous $\Rightarrow$ its graph is closed

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let $X,Y$ topological spaces, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a function, with $Y$ compact.
I need to show that, if $f$ is continuous, so
$$G_{f}:=\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}$$
is closed in $X\times Y$.

I saw that question with $Y$ Hausdorff, so is easy to prove that for every $(x,y)$ with $y\neq f(x)$, there is an open set $U\times V$ such that $U\times V\subset (G_{f})^{c}$ by taking a neighborhood $V$ of $y$ in $Y$ with $f(x)\notin V$.

Can I do that for $Y$ compact? If not, how can I solve this question?

Comment: You need to assume at least $Y$ is $T_1$. For example, take $Y$ with the chaotic topology $\left\{\varnothing,Y\right\}$ and any function $f\colon X\to Y$. Then the graph of $f$ is dense in $X\times Y$.

Comment: In some texts compact is defined as Hausdorff + compact. It is possible the problem came from one that does so.

Comment: Indeed there can be counterexamples if $Y$ is not Hausdorff, see [my post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2325858/4280) for a simple example. If $Y$ is Hausdorff, no compactness at all is needed, just continuity of $f$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that if $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous function if and only if the graph of $f$ is a closed subset of $X\times Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324482/show-that-if-fx-to-y-is-a-continuous-function-if-and-only-if-the-graph-of-f) (As pointed out by Henno Brandsma)